# ODE with initial condition $u$ belonging to Banach Space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, banach-spaces

Let X denote a real Banach space, and consider then the ODE
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
 \mathbf{u}'(t)=A \mathbf{u}(t); \ \ \ (t\geq0)\\
 \mathbf{u}(0)=u,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $'=\frac{d}{dt}, u\in X$ is given, and A is a linear operator. We assume that the ODE has a unique solution for each initial point and we will write
$$\mathbf{u}(t):=S(t) u \ \ \ (t\geq0)$$
to display explicitly the dependence of $\mathbf{u}(t)$ on the initial value $u\in X$.

On my textbook some properties of S(t) are discussed. For example

$$S(t+s)u=S(t)S(s)u=S(s)S(t)u \ \ \ (t,s\geq 0, u\in X).$$

On textbook one can read: "this condition is simply our assumption that the ODE has unique solution for each initial point". I can not understand the link between the previous condition and the uniqueness of the solution. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Loosely speaking, we think $S(t)=exp(tA)$. From what you've stated, it follows immediately from this loose thinking. For a little more rigour, have a look at semi groups in ODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\mathbf u(t):=S(t)u$ as you did. Also, fix $s$ and define $$\mathbf v(t):=S(t+s)u\quad{\rm and}\quad\mathbf w(t):=S(t)S(s)u\, .$$

Then $\mathbf v(t)=\mathbf u(t+s)$, so that
$$\mathbf v'(t)=\mathbf u'(t+s)=A\mathbf u(t+s)=A\mathbf v(t)\, ; $$
moreover, $\mathbf v(0)=S(s)u$.

On the other hand, $\mathbf w(t)$ is *by definition* the solution of the ODE with initial value $S(s)u$.

Hence, $\mathbf v=\mathbf w$ by uniqueness of the solution; which is the required result.

Comment: Does $\mathbf w$ satisfy the ODE? Why?

Comment: Yes it does, by definition, since $\mathbf w(t)=S(t)w$, where $w=S(s)u$.